# Kendo UI for Angular shows warnings when SVG icons are not used

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I upgraded the Kendo UI for Angular to the latest version, and I'm getting multiple warnings like the following in the console:

> Kendo UI for Angular: Icon type is set to 'svg', but only font icon
> name is provided. The "home" font icon will be rendered instead.

The icons are displayed correctly, how to get rid of these messages? I'm not interested in the svg option.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer: by default Kendo now comes set up with SVG icons, to change that default follow these steps:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/icons/icon-settings/#toc-icons-configuration/

This are the settings that need to be configured in @NgModule

```
providers: [
        IconSettingsService,
        {
          provide: ICON_SETTINGS,
          useValue: {
            type: "font"
          },
        },
    ],
```